# Parcel bundler - path to css and js is not linking correctely

Tags: parceljs, parcel

I'm new in parcel using and I don't understand everything.

When I develop my website everything is linking correctely but when I build it it's broken :/

My folder :

```
- src
  index.html
  script.js
  - style
    style.scss
  - rsc
    img1.png
    img2.png
    img3.png
  - part
    part1.html
    part2.html
    part3.html
    - other
      other1.html
      other2.html
      other3.html
```

When it build, style.css is on the root (why not in the "style" folder [who is deleted] ?) and files in "part" folder are linking css on there own folder (`href="style.css"` and not `href="../style.css"`) but there is not css file here. Same for "other" folder (`href="style.css"` and not `href="../../style.css"`).

I use `parcel build src/index.html --public-url ./` to build.

Thanks you everyone <3

Change things in `package.json` but nothing happen.